# Returning variables in parameters in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'm not great at C/C++ and I'm trying to write a function that returns console output like "dir". I am returning the exit code as the main return of the function. I pass the command line as one of the arguments as well as two other variables that I am wanting to store stdout and stderr inside of. The information appears to be getting stored in the variables but it looks like the information is destroyed before I can return it. All I'm looking for is information on returning the info in the variables I have passed. I am sure that the code I post will be awful. Ignore that for now, please. Most of my C/C++ coding isn't usually this extensive and is limited to numbers rather than strings.

```
std::string ReplaceAll(std::string str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to){
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length(); // Handles case where 'to' is a substring of 'from'
    }
    return str;
}
std::string stdoutbuf, stderrbuf = "";
int pipecom(char* cmd, char* qstdout, char* qstderr){
    stdoutbuf = "";
    stderrbuf = "";
    BOOL ok = TRUE;
    HANDLE hStdOutPipeRead, hStdOutPipeWrite, hStdReadPipeError, hStdOutPipeError;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {};
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0;
    sa.bInheritHandle = 1;
    
    if(CreatePipe(&hStdOutPipeRead, &hStdOutPipeWrite, &sa, 0) == FALSE){
        return -1;
    }
    
    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdError = hStdOutPipeError;
    si.hStdOutput = hStdOutPipeWrite;
    si.hStdInput = NULL;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procinfo = {};
    LPSTR lpApplicationName = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes = NULL;
    char * fullcmd = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(cmd) + strlen((LPSTR)"cmd /c "));
    strcpy(fullcmd, (LPSTR)"cmd /c");
    strcat(fullcmd, cmd);
    LPSTR lpCommandLine = (LPSTR)fullcmd;
    BOOL bInheritHandles = TRUE;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
    LPSTR lpEnvironment = NULL;
    LPSTR lpCurrentDirectory = NULL;
    
    ok = CreateProcess(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes, bInheritHandles, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, lpCurrentDirectory, &si, &procinfo);
    
    if(ok == FALSE){
        return -1;
    }
    
    CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeWrite);
    CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeError);
    
    char buf[4096+1] = {};
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    
    while((ReadFile(hStdOutPipeRead, &buf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL) != 0) && (dwRead > 0)){
        buf[dwRead] = '\0';
        stdoutbuf.append(buf);
    }
    memset(buf, 0, 4096+1);
    dwRead = 0;
    while((ReadFile(hStdReadPipeError, &buf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL) !=0) && (dwRead > 0)){
        buf[dwRead] = '\0';
        stderrbuf.append(buf);
    }
    
    DWORD exit_code, ex_stat;
    if(WaitForSingleObject(procinfo.hProcess, INFINITE) != WAIT_FAILED){
        if(GetExitCodeProcess(procinfo.hProcess, &exit_code)){
            ex_stat = 1;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hStdOutPipeRead);
    CloseHandle(hStdReadPipeError);
    
//this is the area of concern
    stdoutbuf = ReplaceAll(stdoutbuf, "\r", "\0");
    stderrbuf = ReplaceAll(stderrbuf, "\r", "\0");
    qstdout = (char *)malloc(1+strlen(stdoutbuf.c_str()));
    qstderr = (char *)malloc(1+strlen(stderrbuf.c_str()));
    strcpy(qstdout, stdoutbuf.c_str());
    strcpy(qstderr, stderrbuf.c_str());
    stdoutbuf.clear();
    stderrbuf.clear();
    if(ex_stat == 1){
        return exit_code;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: For a function to store a value in an argument, and return that changed argument to the caller, the argument must be passed by non-`const` reference or (alternatively) the address of an object must be passed as a pointer.  The first argument of your `ReplaceAll()` is being passed by VALUE.  That means the function receives a COPY of the argument passed by the caller, and any changes made by the function to that argument affect the copy.   That copy ceases to exist before control returns to the caller, so any changes to it are not visible to the caller.

Comment: @pet `ReplaceAll` returns the modified input string to the caller, again, by value. That's a perfectly reasonable implementation, and nothing gets lost or ceases to exist.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
pipecom(char* cmd, char* qstdout, char* qstderr){
```

to

```
pipecom(char* cmd, char** qstdout, char** qstderr){

*qstdout = (char *)malloc(1+strlen(stdoutbuf.c_str()));
*qstderr = (char *)malloc(1+strlen(stderrbuf.c_str()));
```

then dereference and alloc using malloc. otherwise it is just a copy of pointer which will get destroyed once you come out of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really am a novice with C++ so I'm not quite sure what you mean by "dereference". Thank you, again, for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator